# Custom Header in Gridview is repeating (giving 2 headers instead of 1)

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview

Using VB.NET, I have a Gridview control that I created a custom Header for. Works great, except that the Header is repeated twice instead of once. I can't figure out where & why it is repeating. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Here is the Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Vertical" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Hyperlink" DataTextField="Deliverable" HeaderText="Deliverable" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="P1" HeaderText="P1" SortExpression="P1" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="P2" HeaderText="P2" SortExpression="P2" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="P3" HeaderText="P3" SortExpression="P3" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="P4" HeaderText="P4" SortExpression="P4" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="P5" HeaderText="P5" SortExpression="P5" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PMO" HeaderText="PMO" SortExpression="PMO" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="R&D" HeaderText="R&D" SortExpression="R&D" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Marketing" HeaderText="Marketing" SortExpression="Marketing" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Clinical" HeaderText="Clinical" SortExpression="Clinical" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Operations" HeaderText="Operations" SortExpression="Operations" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Quality" HeaderText="Quality" SortExpression="Quality" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Regulatory" HeaderText="Regulatory" SortExpression="Regulatory" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Deliverable" HeaderText="Deliverable" SortExpression="Deliverable" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="DarkBlue" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
            Dim headerCell1 As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim headerCell2 As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim headerCell3 As TableCell = New TableCell()
            Dim headerCell4 As TableCell = New TableCell()

            headerCell1.ColumnSpan = 1
            headerCell1.Text = "Project"
            headerCell1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.DarkBlue
            headerCell1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center

            headerCell2.ColumnSpan = 5
            headerCell2.Text = "Phase"
            headerCell2.BackColor = Drawing.Color.DarkBlue
            headerCell2.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center

            headerCell3.ColumnSpan = 7
            headerCell3.Text = "Stakeholder"
            headerCell3.BackColor = Drawing.Color.DarkBlue
            headerCell3.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center

            headerCell4.ColumnSpan = 1
            headerCell4.Text = "Edit"
            headerCell4.BackColor = Drawing.Color.DarkBlue
            headerCell4.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center

            Dim rowHeader1 As GridViewRow = New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal)
            rowHeader1.Cells.Add(headerCell1)
            rowHeader1.Cells.Add(headerCell2)
            rowHeader1.Cells.Add(headerCell3)
            rowHeader1.Cells.Add(headerCell4)
            rowHeader1.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
            rowHeader1.Font.Bold = True
            rowHeader1.Visible = True

            GridView1.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(0, rowHeader1)

        Else

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: The way I see it, you are binding to datasource1 in aspx file and while handling the row created event, you are creating a new Row and adding to the Header. Hence, two headers.

Answer (score 0):

**You** are adding the second header.

When first header is automatically constructed, you have this line

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
```

Inside the function you have this:

```
    Dim rowHeader1 As GridViewRow = New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal)
        rowHeader1.Cells.Add(headerCell1)
        rowHeader1.Cells.Add(headerCell2)
        rowHeader1.Cells.Add(headerCell3)
        rowHeader1.Cells.Add(headerCell4)
        rowHeader1.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
        rowHeader1.Font.Bold = True
        rowHeader1.Visible = True

        GridView1.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(0, rowHeader1)
```

That's the second header.

Comment: Well, if comment out the last line 'GridView1.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(0, rowHeader1), then both Headers don't get executed. I know I'm the one adding the Header twice but the execution of that last line adds two Headers, not one.